# Table cells don't have an equal width with table-layout: fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a table that contains few columns. I need to columns have an equal width, so I use the following styles:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It works fine in FireFox and Internet Explorer but not in Google Chrome v.43.0.2357.130 m

I've created the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6g4fmu5r/ that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: If you inspect, I think there is something with border (it looks like collapse doesn't work the same), firefox : table have border top and left 1px, td have border right and bottom 1px   /   chrome : table no border, td border all 1px

Comment: maybe check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655987/border-collapse-differences-in-ff-and-webkit

Comment: Chrome, has multiple issues with approximation (rounding up and down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in this post that border-collapse doesn't work the same on Firefox and Chrome :
[Border Collapse differences in FF and Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655987/border-collapse-differences-in-ff-and-webkit)

In Firefox border is only on 2 sides, table complete for top and left.
If you check, you'll see that table have 804 width + 1px border left.
OuterWidth include border, so you'll have 114+1px from right for all td.

In Chrome td have 1px on all side but superpose (0 on table).
Table is also reduce to 804 width, but no border is add...
So Chrome need to reduce 1 td to get the correct width.

Comment: Yes, got it! Thank you, Luckyn! I've updated my sample - http://jsfiddle.net/ejq9fz7z/

Comment: you don't have to add css for td:first-child.

Comment: In my case, I want to add 1px-border to each cell. If I apply `border: 1px solid` for all cells, I'll get double vertical borders. http://jsfiddle.net/sergfry/ejq9fz7z/1/

Comment: I personnaly like firefox way... So you can add border on all except left and add the last left border to the first cell `td { border: 1px solid green; border-left:0; } td:first-child {border-left:1px solid green;}`  (and if you add some rows do the same for bottom or top border) http://jsfiddle.net/ejq9fz7z/2/

Answer (score 1):

After testing a lot things i got the solution..

please replace this code

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 805px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

to this

```
table {
    width: 805px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

and you will get all equal width td..:)

refference : [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591499/chrome-bug-with-colspan-and-border)